# Use custom FOR loop?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, foreach

Simple question,
**just for fun**.

I want to create a category or *something similar*, "*sublassing*" FOR loop, to make a **FOREACH** in obectivec, **or to make a custom loop**.

Ok, FOR loop is not a class and we cannot make a category or subclassing. We know.

I could use `for (MyObj *obj in _MyArray ) { }`, but i don't want.
I want to do this:

```
foreach (MyObj *obj in _MyArray) { }
```

Or better a custom FOR loop, that make something different then classic FOR loop.

**Note**: not want a macro / define.

suggestions?
It's possible to make something similar or not?

---

## EDIT

**Thanks to downvote, especially without comments!

If you don't like this question or this question not have a response, ignore it, or better drop a comment!**

Comment: A for loop is not an object. How can you possibly subclass it? Also, what are you trying to achieve with your custom loop?

Comment: Why don't you like `for`?  It's the Objective-C way of doing foreach.  It's no different to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define foreach for
foreach (MyObj *obj in _MyArray) { }
```

Comment: hahaha great! I not want to use a macro, but i like this way! :)

Comment: By the way you can also write something like:
`please_perform_the_following_block_of_code_foreach (MyObj *obj in _MyArray) { }`

Just define it like this:
`#define please_perform_the_following_block_of_code_foreach for`

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

"for" is not a class, you can't subclass it.

Obj-C does have a for..in syntax that you can use for the case you describe.  It looks like this:

```
for (MyObj *obj in _MyArray)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Then use a different language.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at LLVM Clang and how to extend the language parser. If you do not want to use macros, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`for (MyObj *obj in _MyArray ) { }` is all you need.